# How to load images async with Bearer Authorization using Angular2 & NPM

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, bearer-token

I'm looking for a recent solution using Angular2. I have a list of images, so in my template, I do:

```
<div *ngFor="let myImg of myImages">
    <img src="{{myImg}}" />
</div>
```

myImages are an array loaded in my component.ts:

```
myImages: string[] = new Array();
```

This is the Postman and the API call I am trying to model after:
[image]

What is the best way to do this in angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's a way to do that since the browsers usually don't usually allow you to set the authentication header on img elements.

Your best alternative would be to retrieve the image with a separate http request using the http service and then set the source later with that value.

Preferably the response would be the image base64 encoded so you can set it as the source for the img tag but there are ways to convert binary to base64 on the client side.